# Returning a pointer in C++

Tags: c++

I think my question sounds stupid and welcome downvote on me. If you are implementing a method in C++ which needs to return a pointer, is it safe to do that? If not, why?

Comment: Without code samples, you might consider your question not havwíng been asked at all ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not a simple question. For instance: [Best way of returning a pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11275360/best-way-of-returning-a-pointer?rq=1).

Ideally, you should try to avoid returning values that come with side-effects or obligations.

```
// This may be ok, it implies no burden on the user.
Manager* GetManager();
// But what if the user decides to call delete on the value you return?

// This is not unusual in C code, but carries a hidden contract:
// I allocate - you free.
const char* GetFilename(int fd)
{
    char* filename = malloc(256);
    sprintf(filename, "/tmp/tmpfile.%d", fd);
    return filename;
}
```

C++ is about encapsulation and abstraction. You can codify the contract with your consumer by encapsulating a pointer you want to return. The idea here is that instead of exposing a pointer, you expose an object which is responsible for ownership of the pointer. Infact, recent versions of the language already do this for you with std::unique_ptr, std::shared_ptr and std::weak_ptr.

But a crude, simple RAII example might be:

```
class StrDupPtr
{
    char* m_alloc;
public:
    StrDupPtr(const char* src)
        : m_alloc(strdup(src))
    {}

    ~StrDupPtr()
    {
        free(m_alloc);
    }

    operator const char* () const { return m_alloc; }

    // etc.
};
```

You're still returning a pointer here, but you've encapsulated it with a management contract and removed burden from the end-user to manage your resources.

You can't always avoid it, and when you have to, yes it can be dangerous.

```
int* AllocateMeSomeMemory()
{
    int* memory = malloc(4 * sizeof(int));
    // here, have four ints.
    return memory;
}

int main() {
    int* memory = AllocateMeSomeMemory();
    memory[42] = 0xDeath; // yeah, it's not a valid hex number, but that's not really the problem.
}
```

Another common problem with pointers is that there's no way to tell how many people have them. Here's a contrived example:

```
void transferItem(userid_t user1, userid_t user2, itemid_t item) {
    Account* a1 = GetAccount(user1);
    Account* a2 = GetAccount(user2);

    if (a1 != a2) {
        transferItemInternal(a1, a2, item);
    }

    delete a2;
    delete a1;  // Sorry Dave, I can't do that. How about a nice game of CRASH?
}
```

Normally, a2 and a1 will be different, but when they're not...

Another common failure pattern with pointers is asynchronous callbacks:

```
// ask the database for user details, call OnLoginResult with userObj when we're done.
void login(int socket, userid_t userId, passwordhash_t pass) {
    User* userObj = GetUserObj(userId, socket);
    Query* query = Database()->NewQuery("SELECT * FROM user WHERE id = ? AND password = ?", userId, pass);
    Database()->Queue(query, OnLoginResult, userObj);
}

void OnDisconnect(int socket, int reason) {
    User* userObj = GetUserBySocket(socket);
    if (userObj) {
        UnregisterUserObj(userObj);
        delete userObj;
    }
}

void OnLoginResult(void* param) {
    User* userObj = static_cast<UserObj*>(param);
    // all well and good unless the user disconnected while waiting.
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is. I assume you mean "Allocate and return" a pointer.

Its  common to have initialisation functions which allocate a pointer to an object of some type, and then initialise the object itself. It will then be up to a different part of the program to release the memory.

Comment: Define 'safe' with exact requirements of the OP ...

Answer (score 0):

Well it always depends on what you are doing. A pointer is simply a memory address, so it is similar to simply returning an integer. You should do more research on pointers and how to properly implement them

Comment: Pretty broad answer, as the question is in turn! Wh at does _'safe return'_ mean by definitions of the question?

Answer (score 0):

I sense this question might be closed quite soon, but I'll try to answer anyway.

Yes, it's "safe", as long as you're careful. In fact, it's a very common way to do things, particularly  if you're interfacing with C APIs. Having said that, it's best to avoid doing so if you can, because C++ generally provides better alternatives.

Why should you avoid it? Firstly, let's say you have a method that looks like this:

```
MyStruct* get_data();
```

Is the return value a pointer to a single instance of `MyStruct`, or the start of an array? Do you need to `free()` the returned pointer? Or perhaps you need to use `delete`? Can the return value be `NULL`, and what happens if it is? Without looking at the documentation, you have no way of knowing any of these things. And the compiler has no way of knowing either, so it can't help you out in any way.

Better options:

If you want to return an array of values, use a `std::array` (if the size is fixed at compile-time), or a `std::vector` (if the size isn't known till run-time).

If you're trying to avoid copying a large struct, then return a reference, or a const reference if possible. That way the caller knows they won't receive a `NULL` value.

If you really need to return a pointer, than consider using a smart pointer instead -- that will help you sort out ownership issues. For example, `std::shared_ptr` uses reference counting, and `std::unique_ptr` ensures that a given pointer only ever has one owner.